# Change the Main Body Background Colour dependant on current Razor Page

Tags: css, asp.net-core, background-color, razor-pages

I am working on a basic Razor Pages web app which has three main pages. I want to be able to change the body's background colour depending on which Razor Page the user is currently viewing.

The body is contained in the `_Layout.cshtml` file where I am able to change the colour for the whole app:

```
<body style="background-color: lightcoral ">
```

However at this late hour in the day I cannot seem to figure out how I can change this colour depending on the page I am currently on. My initial thought is to look at using JQuery to get the body element and update the background style attribute through there, but I am still not certain how I tell which page I am currently on to decide the colour.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add different background colors to different areas,you can add body id with current area name,and add styles to different ids.Here is a demo:

_layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    var routeUrl = this.Url.RouteUrl(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
    var area = routeUrl.Split("/")[1];
}
<body id="@area">
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">RazorPageWithAreas</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Entry" asp-page="/Create">Entry/Create</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Session" asp-page="/Create">Session/Create</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Trip" asp-page="/Create">Trip/Create</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

...

<style>
    #Session {
        background-color: #ffefef;
    }

    #Trip {
        background-color: #fff8d7;
    }

    #Entry {
        background-color: #eafff3;
    }
</style>
</body>
```

folder structure:

[image]

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I have come up with this which works, however the background is still flickering white when I navigate between pages. I would be interested to hear anyone else's solutions that might be better, more performant... Even to include some transitions ;)

I have three areas each containing a Create, Edit, Details, Index, Delete page. The Areas are Season, Trip, Entry. So, for each page under Season I have added a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnPageSelector" id="hdnSeasonPage" />
```

Each page under Trip I have added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnPageSelector" id="hdnTripPage" />
```

and each page under Entry I have added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnPageSelector" id="hdnEntryPage" />
```

Then I have a piece of Javascript/JQuery that executes on `DOMCONTENTLOADED`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    var pageId = $("[name ='hdnPageSelector']").attr('id');

    if (pageId == "hdnSeasonPage") {
        $("body,html").css("background-color", "#ffefef");
    }
    if (pageId == "hdnTripPage") {
        $("body,html").css("background-color", "#fff8d7");
    }
    if (pageId == "hdnEntryPage") {
        $("body,html").css("background-color", "#eafff3");
    }
});
```

As I mentioned, this seems to work but would be interested in hearing some better solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a value in `ViewData` in your code and then just use that in the layout page

```
<body style="background-color: @ViewData["BackgroundColor"]">
```

Personally I would probably use a class to drive this

```
<body class=" @ViewData["BackgroundClass"]">
```